# How to write Kafka Connect query to query data between two specific dates using timestamp mode

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am writing a Kakfa JDBC Source Connector to query between two dates(starting and ending date) in a Postgres Table and want Connector run the query for every day starting from the ending date to the starting date.Is it possible ?
select * from table where date is between '2020-08-01' and ending_date='2020-10-31'

Comment: You're writing your own, or configuring the existing one?? What happens when you give this query to the connector currently?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [Confluent Filter SMT](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-confluent.html) by defining a `filter.condition`.

An example is presented in the link and shown below:

```
transforms=filterDateExample
# Use the 'io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value' as the source (record 'value') on which
# 'filter.condition' shall be applied.
transforms.filterDateExample.type=io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value
transforms.filterDateExample.filter.condition=$.key[?(@.date >= "2020-08-01" && @.date <= "2020-10-31")]
# Use 'include' to pass through all records that match the predicate.
transforms.filterDateExample.filter.type=include
# Use the 'fail' behavior to throw an exception and fail the connector task when the record does
# not have the field(s) used in the 'filter.condition'.
transforms.filterDateExample.missing.or.null.behavior=fail
```

It does not look like it recognises the date type, so you may also want to look into the [Timestamp Converter](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/timestampconverter.html).